# Update SQL doesn't work. No Error

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code for updating. it displays "Done" but if you check the database, the fields are not updating.

What's wrong with my code?

```php
<?php include('include/dbconnect.php');

$page = $_POST['newpage'];
$title = $_POST['newtitle'];
$content = $_POST['newcontent'];
$track_no = $_POST['track_no'];
$done = "UPDATE contents SET page = '$page',title = '$title', content = '$content', modified = 'CURDATE()'WHERE track_no = '$track_no' ";     
$result = mysql_query($done) or die(mysql_error());
if (!$result)
{
    print "Something is wrong!";
}
else{
    print "Done!";
}

?>
```

Comment: remove '' after modfied as currdate is function

Comment: Echo your query and run in phpmyadmin. May be there you can see error

Comment: Stack Snippets are meant for use with pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. They do not work with server-side languages like SQL and PHP at this time.

Comment: @nhinkle thanks and i used to think those links are just some kind of add. I am new here

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 0):

just remove quote from your sql

```
$done = "UPDATE contents SET page = '$page',title = '$title', content = '$content', modified = CURDATE() WHERE track_no = '$track_no' ";
```

Comment: This wouldn't result in a query not working, it would only result in the field being `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score -1):

your doing right one, but silly mistake only, **`YOU SHOULD MUST REMOVE THE SINGLE QUOTE IN CURDATE`** like as,

```
$done = "UPDATE contents SET 
page = '$page',
title = '$title', 
content = '$content', 
modified = CURDATE() 
WHERE 
track_no = '$track_no' ";
```

***Note: Any kind of date or time don't mention in quote. Not this one 0000-00-00 00-00-00***

Comment: This wouldn't result in a query not working, it would only result in the field being `0000-00-00`. Also, date or time values HAVE to have quotes. Function calls can't have quotes.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25946267/3640589] @GeraldSchneider how did you score 5000 and above, hey you should must learn the mysql your query doesn't work, **because your missing the  single quote** you should must changed the query and after u'll advise others....

Comment: @GeraldSchneider do you want a upvote means tell me i'll give you, don't doing like this...